# Pass list of records from Apex to Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

**> My case is simple:** I want to pass a list of ContentDocumentLink records from my Apex list to a flow, in order to do stuff with them.

Here is my trigger:

```
    trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {    
    if (Trigger.IsInsert) {
        if (Trigger.IsAfter) {
            EM_ContentDocumentLink.fireContentDocumentLinkFlow(Trigger.new);
            }
    }
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class EM_ContentDocumentLink {
    public static void fireContentDocumentLinkFlow(List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL) { 
                
        //declare new map with String (as my flowVariable name) and List (as my listCDL)
        Map<String, List<ContentDocumentLink>> params = new Map<String, List<ContentDocumentLink>>(); 
        
        //put my flowVariable and listCDL in the new map
        params.put('flowListCDL', listCDL);
                        
        //declare flow instance with the CLD
        Flow.Interview.ClientOrderSendPOD PODflow = new Flow.Interview.ClientOrderSendPOD(params);
        PODflow.start();      
    }
}
```

I created my flowListCDL on my Flow:
[image]

**> Problem is:** my flow does not do anything, I noticed, in the developer console, that it starts and ends in the same second. It could be that the list is not passed accordingly to my flow.

What do you think is happening?

Comment: When posting to the **Salesforce** Stack Exchange, it is implicit that your questions pertain to the platform. You do not need to add any tags or title to convey that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was as simple as: I created a list of Content Document Links in which I passed the list of CDLs coming in the parameters... for some reason, this worked.

**Code:**

```
    public class EM_ContentDocumentLink {
    public static String fireContentDocumentLinkFlow(List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL) { 
        //I passed my listCDL to myCDLs       
        List<ContentDocumentLink> myCDLs = listCDL;  
                
        Map<String, List<ContentDocumentLink>> params = new Map<String, List<ContentDocumentLink>>();

        params.put('flowListCDL', myCDLs);
                                
        Flow.Interview myFlow = New Flow.Interview.myFlowAPIname(params);
        PODflow.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and adding your answer - you can also mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below code where flowName is your name of your flow

```
Flow.Interview.ClientOrderSendPOD PODflow = new Flow.Interview.ClientOrderSendPOD(params);
        PODflow.start();
```

to

```
 Flow.Interview PODflow = Flow.Interview.createInterview(flowName, params);
        PODflow.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my code as you requested, however, I am getting the following error: Variable does not exist: ClientOrderSendPOD

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I apologise for not replying sooner, Sahil. I had a very hectic journey at work. I posted the solution as an answer to my question. Please, check it out if you want.